# Is there a way to open FIFO(named pipe) in write-only way without blocked

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, fifo

I use `FIFO` in my server. Due to some limitations, I have to open the `FIFO` in write-only firstly, then I use `fork` to create another process to open `FIFO` in read-only. But I find that, it will be blocked when I open the `FIFO` in write-only firstly, thus the server can not continue to run to `fork`.

For some reason I can not open `FIFO` in read-only firstly, Is there a way to open `FIFO` in write-only without blocked? I have tried `open("/tmp/ngfifo", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK)` but will return `error`

The small example is like this :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    int pipe_fd = open("/tmp/ngfifo", O_WRONLY);  // It will be blocked here, is there a way to open without block.
    if(pipe_fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened fifo failed %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("wait..\n");

    if (fork() > 0) {
        printf("begin to write \n");
    } else {
        int read_fd = open("/tmp/ngfifo", O_RDONLY);
        // ...
        printf("begin to read \n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't open the FIFO until after you have forked the child. Secondly, what are you currently doing to block your program? Please create a [mre] to show us what you're doing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added a small example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Linux FIFO man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> Under Linux, opening a FIFO for read and write will succeed both in blocking and nonblocking mode.  POSIX leaves this behavior undefined.  This can be used to open a FIFO for writing while there are no readers available.

So on Linux, it is possible for the writing process to call `open("/tmp/ngfifo", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)` to open the write end of the pipe without blocking because it is also open for reading. However, this is not portable to other operating systems.

Comment: I have tried this `int pipe_fd = open("/tmp/ngfifo", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);` on centos 7.5, it returned -1, and the `errno` is `ENXIO   6`

Comment: @Klen Yes, that is expected when the FIFO is not already open for reading. Replacing `O_WRONLY` with `O_RDWR` as in the answer ensures it is open for both reading and writing, so it should open successfully (if the file's permissions are OK). (This is a Linux hack. POSIX does not define opening a FIFO with `O_RDWR`.)

Answer (score 3):

From [the FIFO manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html):

> Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.

The solution is simple: Open the file *after* you have forked your child process.

Comment: I want to know , if I have to open it before fork, can it not be solved?

Comment: @Klen No. As documented, it *will* block your process.